# Vertically aligning an image in a column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and I can't seem to find the solution for vertically centering an image inside of a div. I've looked around and found multiple different solutions but none are actually working for me.

[Here's an image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gFpZ.png)

I need to get that image vertically centered so that it is in line with the text. Here's an edited version of what I need it to look like.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSE0M.png)

I need it to be responsive with the text, so I can't just add a margin there.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row row-padding" id="bg-white">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080/" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
      <h4>Fugiat senserit litteris, hic consequat graviterque. Quo te elit cupidatat e ut 
                                minim occaecat adipisicing ex officia ea ullamco, fore tractavissent mentitum 
                                malis aliquip, lorem ut doctrina se incididunt sempiternum ita proident, nescius 
                                quis an probant cohaerescant, aut aliqua officia iudicem. An sunt admodum, est 
                                ut eram quae eram. Nulla ubi mandaremus do tamen an arbitror nam velit, 
                                expetendis ipsum sint ita nulla nam aut varias quid non nostrud. Quorum pariatur 
                                aut sint tamen aut nescius sint eiusmod. Ex quae nostrud, ea dolore appellat, 
                                iis illum proident admodum ne est tempor familiaritatem. Hic anim 
                                instituendarum, an sed multos quae multos.</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks,
Daniel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best so far i've found is this:

howtocenterincss.com

It will tell you how to center anything into any other thing, either vertically or horizontally.
Just take care of not messing the rest of the layout.

So for your specific use case:

We don't know the height of the text, neither the size of the image, it's inline-block element.

Response:
    `<div style="display:flex;align-items:center;">Text Content</div>`

So we apply:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row row-padding" id="bg-white">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-6" style="display:flex;align-items:center;">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080/" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
      <h4>Fugiat senserit litteris, hic consequat graviterque. Quo te elit cupidatat e ut 
                                minim occaecat adipisicing ex officia ea ullamco, fore tractavissent mentitum 
                                malis aliquip, lorem ut doctrina se incididunt sempiternum ita proident, nescius 
                                quis an probant cohaerescant, aut aliqua officia iudicem. An sunt admodum, est 
                                ut eram quae eram. Nulla ubi mandaremus do tamen an arbitror nam velit, 
                                expetendis ipsum sint ita nulla nam aut varias quid non nostrud. Quorum pariatur 
                                aut sint tamen aut nescius sint eiusmod. Ex quae nostrud, ea dolore appellat, 
                                iis illum proident admodum ne est tempor familiaritatem. Hic anim 
                                instituendarum, an sed multos quae multos.</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is a comment not an answser, unless you want to set up an example in a snippet and explanation around it :)

Answer (score 0):

- You may override bootstrap with a class and use flex .
- [or look for the flex version of bootstrap](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/) and use built-in classes

add a class and css

```css
.flex {
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:wrap;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row row-padding" id="bg-white">
  <div class="container flex">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080/" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
      <h4>Fugiat senserit litteris, hic consequat graviterque. Quo te elit cupidatat e ut 
                                minim occaecat adipisicing ex officia ea ullamco, fore tractavissent mentitum 
                                malis aliquip, lorem ut doctrina se incididunt sempiternum ita proident, nescius 
                                quis an probant cohaerescant, aut aliqua officia iudicem. An sunt admodum, est 
                                ut eram quae eram. Nulla ubi mandaremus do tamen an arbitror nam velit, 
                                expetendis ipsum sint ita nulla nam aut varias quid non nostrud. Quorum pariatur 
                                aut sint tamen aut nescius sint eiusmod. Ex quae nostrud, ea dolore appellat, 
                                iis illum proident admodum ne est tempor familiaritatem. Hic anim 
                                instituendarum, an sed multos quae multos.</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

link to bootstrap, flex version, and use classes :  `d-flex  flex-wrap align-items-cent`

```css
img {
  max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="row row-padding" id="bg-white">
   <div class="container d-flex  flex-wrap align-items-center">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080/" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
      <h4>Fugiat senserit litteris, hic consequat graviterque. Quo te elit cupidatat e ut 
                                minim occaecat adipisicing ex officia ea ullamco, fore tractavissent mentitum 
                                malis aliquip, lorem ut doctrina se incididunt sempiternum ita proident, nescius 
                                quis an probant cohaerescant, aut aliqua officia iudicem. An sunt admodum, est 
                                ut eram quae eram. Nulla ubi mandaremus do tamen an arbitror nam velit, 
                                expetendis ipsum sint ita nulla nam aut varias quid non nostrud. Quorum pariatur 
                                aut sint tamen aut nescius sint eiusmod. Ex quae nostrud, ea dolore appellat, 
                                iis illum proident admodum ne est tempor familiaritatem. Hic anim 
                                instituendarum, an sed multos quae multos.</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```